# how to add a new page like sales/order/history

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, template, customer-account, order-status

I want to add a new customer page (sales/order/unpaid-history) like sales/order/history in customer menu, it shows all the unpaid order with status pending_payment. Same template, same data, but has a condition filter.

Can modify magento core file, simple the best

My thought is copy the sales/order layout file, add a new phtml template, add a new method in sales order model. Is it right?

thanks for your help

Comment: my magento version is 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

**Don't modify core files!**

Magento adds the history tab in `sales.xml` as follows:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

You can use the same layout update in a custom module:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="your_module"><name>unpaid_history</name><path>your/controller/unpaidHistory/</path><label>Unpaid History</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

This will add a link "Unpaid History" pointing to `your/controller/unpaidHistory`

For the layout of your custom controller, you can look again, how Magento does it with the history:

```
<sales_order_history translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Order History</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_history" name="sales.order.history">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="sales.order.history.info" as="info" translate="label">
                <label>Order History Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_history>
```

Copy it to your layout file, replace `sales_order_history` with `your_controller_unpaidHistory` and replace the `<block type="sales/order_history">` block with your custom block and custom template.